# How to extract a condition in a known line using JDT-AST?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I have a method like this:

```
public static int calc(int a, int b) {
        if (a >= b)
            return a - b;
        return 0;
}
```

I want to know the condition that is used on a known line number. In this case my expected result is the name of the condition, something like ">=".

I know how to parse the `CompilationUnit` of a given `ICompilationUnit`. But how can I get the condition(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to create an ASTVisitor which will visit all the infix expressions. In the visitor class the visit method will have the following:

```
@Override
public boolean visit(InfixExpression node) {
    Operator op= node.getOperator();
    if(op.equals(Operator.GREATER) || op.equals(Operator.EQUALS) || ....)
        conditionalInfixExpressionList.add(node);
    return super.visit(node);
}
```

In the if statement inside of the `visit` method, you have to check, if the infix expression is a conditional variables and accordingly add it to the list.